# Trapping filtered Intents from android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

From my understanding, if an intent is invoked implicitly, android matches the intent object's contents against all intent filters in the following order: component,  action, data and category, filtering out non-matching intents at each step. At this point if there are multiple intents filtered out, then it brings up the activity chooser.

Is there a way by which I can trap the final filtered result and do further filtering based on Extras and Flags? Would `ResolveInfo` be of any help to me in this case?

In effect, I want to process my custom logic before android brings up the Activity chooser.

Can someone please point me in the right direction, maybe a place in the android source code which helps me to do the above?!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are the one calling `startActivity()`, you can use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to find out what the chooser would wind up showing. You can then roll your own chooser if you, er, choose.

If you are trying to intercept the starting of any and all activities on the device, this is not possible.